# How can I make the a Hyperlink so user can go to that specific website .Im using .putExtras

Tags: java, android

I have added the details inside the displayItems activity after user click the item on Listview. The question is how can I make the URL clickable so user can got to that specific website.(The details is called from csv file). Anyone can guide me?

My Listview.java

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingMall.this, Displayitem.class);
            if (adapter.getItem(position).length > 0) {
                intent.putExtra(Displayitem.EXTRA_NAME, adapter.getItem(position)[1]);
                intent.putExtra(Displayitem.EXTRA_STATE, adapter.getItem(position)[2]);
                intent.putExtra(Displayitem.EXTRA_ADDRESS, adapter.getItem(position)[4]);
                intent.putExtra(Displayitem.EXTRA_URL, adapter.getItem(position)[5]);
                intent.putExtra(Displayitem.EXTRA_NUMBER, adapter.getItem(position)[6]);
                intent.putExtra(Displayitem.EXTRA_MAIL, adapter.getItem(position)[7]);

            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

My displayItem.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_displayitem);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    tvMallName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mallname);
    state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.states);
    mallAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mall_Address);
    url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);
    phone_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
    mail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mail);


    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String malladress = extras.getString(EXTRA_ADDRESS,"");
    String mallName = extras.getString(EXTRA_NAME, "");
    String mallurl = extras.getString(EXTRA_URL,"-");
    String mallnumber = extras.getString(EXTRA_NUMBER,"-");
    String mallstate = extras.getString(EXTRA_STATE,"");
    String mallmail = extras.getString(EXTRA_MAIL,"-");

    mallAddress.setText(malladress);
    tvMallName.setText(mallName);
    state.setText(mallstate);
    url.setText(mallurl);
    mail.setText(mallmail);
    phone_number.setText(mallnumber);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Methode 1 :**

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

**Method 2:**

use `android:autoLink="web"` in your TextView's xml. It should automatically   convert urls click-able (if found in text)
 Also include `android:linksClickable="true"`

Comment: Thank you, I prefer the 2nd method haha.. Problem solved. TYVM

Answer (score 1):

Put this piece of code in `onClick` method of of textview. This will launch the browser with the specified URL

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(YOUR_URL));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks , it helps me when i set it on specific website.